# Segmentation fault when executing a command in rc.local

Tags: x11, startup

I'm trying to execute `xbindkeys -f /etc/xbindkeysrc` command on the start up. I've put this in my `rc.local` including another command :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
xbindkeys -f /etc/xbindkeysrc
exit 0
```

But then i find that `xbindkeys` command didn't get executed.

I've checked `/var/log/messages` and found this line :

```
rc.local[1194]: /etc/rc.d/rc.local: line 4:  1203 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) xbindkeys -f /etc/xbindkeysrc
```

Could you tell me please, what does `segmentation fault` mean ? and how to avoid it ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault

Comment: It could be that `rc.local` is something that happens before X is initiated. Do you start X in `.profile`, `.zprofile` or the like?

Answer (score 2):

You can't run `xbindkeys` in the `/etc/rc.local` script because the X11 server isn't running yet. You should put commands that require X11 to be running in this file instead, `$HOME/.xinitrc`.

Don't worry if this file doesn't exist, simply make it and add this line to it:

Here's some background info on xinitrc:

- [Slackware Linux Essentials - 6.3 xinitrc](http://www.slackbook.org/html/x-window-system-xinitrc.html)
- [ArchLinux Wiki - xinitrc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc)

  xbindkeys -f /etc/xbindkeysrc