# xbindkeys won't run in ExecStart script but runs in regular script

Tags: debian, systemd, xbindkeys

I have a script `start.sh` which is the `ExecStart` of a service I have (that is called by systemd).

When I add the line `DISPLAY=:0 xbindkeys` in my `start.sh` script, it does not start `xbindkeys`.

```
user@host:~$ service SERVICE status
● SERVICE.service - "MY AWESOME SERVICE"
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/SERVICE.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-03-05 21:44:22 CET; 13min ago
 Main PID: 5508 (bash)
   CGroup: /system.slice/SERVICE.service
           ├─5508 /bin/bash /home/user/start.sh
           └─5530 /usr/lib/PROGRAM

Mar 05 21:44:24 HOSTNAME bash[5508]: <SOME LOGS>
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
user@host:~$ ps -ef | grep xbindkeys
user      6181  3545  0 21:57 pts/1    00:00:00 grep xbindkeys
user@host:~$
```

I've also tried making a separate service and making my original service depend on it:

```
[Unit]
Description="Xbindkeys Service to block keys"
Before=SERVICE.service
Requires=SERVICE.service

[Service]
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xbindkeys
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I cannot start it

```
user@host:~$ service xbindkeys status
● xbindkeys.service - "Xbindkeys Service to block keys"
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/xbindkeys.service; disabled)
  Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Thu 2020-03-05 21:47:37 CET; 1s ago
  Process: 6122 ExecStart=/usr/bin/xbindkeys -X :0 (code=killed, signal=SEGV)
 Main PID: 6122 (code=killed, signal=SEGV)

Mar 05 21:47:37 HOST systemd[1]: Unit xbindkeys.service entered failed state.
Mar 05 21:47:37 HOST systemd[1]: xbindkeys.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 05 21:47:37 HOST systemd[1]: Stopping "Xbindkeys Service to block keys"...
Mar 05 21:47:37 HOST systemd[1]: Starting "Xbindkeys Service to block keys"...
Mar 05 21:47:37 HOST systemd[1]: xbindkeys.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Mar 05 21:47:37 HOST systemd[1]: Failed to start "Xbindkeys Service to block keys".
Mar 05 21:47:37 HOST systemd[1]: Unit xbindkeys.service entered failed state.
```

I've also tried changing the `ExecStart` of the `xbindkeys.service` in various ways:

- `ExecStart=/usr/bin/xbindkeys -X :0`

They all don't work and result in the same output above.

When I call `DISPLAY=:0 xbindkeys` from my terminal, `xbindkeys` works as expected and runs in the background as a process until I kill it.

```
~$ xbindkeys
~$ ps -ef | grep xbindkeys
user      6166     1  0 21:54 ?        00:00:00 xbindkeys
user      6168  3545  0 21:54 pts/1    00:00:00 grep xbindkeys
~$
```

Also if I have a simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# start-xbindkeys.sh

DISPLAY=:0 xbindkeys
```

It also runs in the background as expected if I call the script via `./start-xbindkeys.sh`

```
~$ ./start-xbindkeys.sh
~$ ps -ef | grep xbindkeys
user      6166     1  0 21:54 ?        00:00:00 xbindkeys
user      6168  3545  0 21:54 pts/1    00:00:00 grep xbindkeys
~$
```

**Why would I not be able to run `xbindkeys` via `systemd`?**

*I am running this on an i386 Debian 8 Jessie system.*

Comment: Reading Debian bug 516565 and Ubuntu bug 1063224 does make it seem that crashing with a segmentation fault is just how xbindkeys programs report errors.  (-:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80943/5132 is a related question.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the exact same problem